# error:040A1079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error On AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, cryptojs

I use the crypto package to do the following :

1. crypto.generateKeyPairSync() to generate publicKey and privateKey

   - I only created the keys once, and stored them in the .env file
2. crypto.publicEncrypt() to encrypt data before storing it into the database
3. crypto.privateDecrypt() to decrpyt data to render on HTML page
   (rendering data on html page is just to check if data has been stored correctly, I will later use privateDecrypt during login to check if pw is valid).

On my local computer:

1. I am able to encrypt the data and store it in the DB
2. Decrypt the data and render it on HTML

However, if I try to decrypt the data on the AWS EC2 instance, I get the following error: error:040A1079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error.

I am very confused because I am using the exact same keys, exact code, and exact DB. What works fine locally does not work at AWS. What could be the problem here?

```
const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto');
const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
  modulusLength: 4096,
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'spki',
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs8',
    format: 'pem',
    cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
    passphrase: 'top secret'
  }

const ENCRYPTED_pw = crypto.publicEncrypt(
                    {
                        key: PUBLIC_KEY,
                        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
                        oaepHash: "sha256",
                    },
                    Buffer.from(body.pw)
                );
                //convert Array Buffer to String 
                let encryptedPW = ENCRYPTED_pw.toString("base64");
//INSERT data into DB HERE

//GET data from DB HERE

let decryptedPhoneNum = crypto.privateDecrypt(
                            {
                                key: PRIVATE_KEY,
                                padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
                                oaepHash: "sha256",
                            },
                            Buffer.from(result[i].pw, "base64")
                        );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

(I happened to see this question on my way to check other questions. And writing this opinion just in case it may help your problem.)

When I saw your error message, I assumed that it may have a problem with `padding`.

So I checked your `padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` code and noticed that `crypto` variable never declared when you import it, rather you declared only `generateKeyPairSync` from the `crypto` like this,

> ```js
> const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto');
> ```

Following this [`crypto` part of Node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html), they declare the `crypto` variable on the top of their code when importing.

> ```js
> const crypto = require('crypto');
> ```

Hope this may help your problem.

Comment: The code is working fine locally, I just have a problem when I'm trying to run it using a EC2 instance on AWS. I only brought a portion of the source code, but thank you for mentioning it